# How to read an online docx file and webscrape table contents, with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to web-scrape an online secure docx file. I am able to successfully get it with the following:

r = requests.get("https://the_full_path.docx", auth=HttpNtlmAuth('uid','pwd'))

but now i am stumped with how to read this object and also dig deeper into the file structure to extract what i require .

Answer (score 0):

I found a snippet where i create a .docx file and store the incoming stream to it. I shall be continuing with my search of how to read off of the local file, but i have seen examples for that kind of search.

```
with open('myfile.docx', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(1024 * 1024 * 2):  # 2 MB chunks
        f.write(chunk)
```